# Import modules from Airflow

Tags: python, path, airflow

Need help importing modules from dags.
I have a dag, next to which in the same folder is my python script.
For some reason airflow does not see this file and it shows import error.

[image]

Below you can see that status_dict.by is next to my dag.

[image]

I partially solved the problem by creating a commons package and importing my python scripts.
To create a common I use the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='commons', version='0.0.6', author='Alexander Brezhnev', author_email='brezhnev.aleksandr@gmail.com',
      packages=find_packages())
```

Can someone tell me how to use scripts in the dag that are in the same folder with the current dag?

I'm trying to import a python script from a dag, but I'm getting an import error.

That helped:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add `__init__.py` file in your SQL folder? I remember that I faced a similar error a few years ago with an Airflow docker image and managed to fix it that way.

Comment: Yes! It really helped. 
I additionally specified the path to the file in this way: from report_25.status_dict import status_dict. 
And it worked.